# Was the WD1761 series binned FD1791's, or an entirely separate line?

Tags: floppy-drive

I am wondering if anyone out there is familiar enough with the FD179x series floppy controllers to comment on whether they were simply binned FD179x's, or a separate line entirely? It seems the only difference is the supported clock rate?

Comment: I guess the first FD179x in the question body should be WD1761? Apologies for having no more useful comment than that. The WD177x are definitely not binned versions of either, differing slightly in terms of motor control versus head loading if memory serves, but that’s another question again. I’m unfamiliar with the WD176x.

Comment: It isn't uncommon to make one chip die and connect it differently in multiple packaged versions... or even just put different pin strapping requirements in the datasheets of variant types that will actually select the operations mode (see 8031/8051) ...